# Cycles per byte of 128-bit LCG

Tags: time-complexity

Let's consider 128-bit LCG with modulus $2^n$ of the form:

$X_{n+1}=a \cdot X_{n} + c \mod 2^{128}$

How fast we can run it in cycles per byte? And how much of RAM it required?

Comment: The answer to the first question depends on the CPU. I believe you can answer the second one on your own (on first sight, it doesn't seem like lookup tables are helpful here).